# tweepy unable to connect to twitter- No error returned

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

I am a beginner at python . I'm trying to get the follower counts of a given user handle from twitter. The issue is that tweepy is not connecting to twitter and is not even returning any error. The terminal just stays blank. Please help on this.

```
import tweepy
import pymysql
import time

#insert your Twitter keys here
consumer_key =''
consumer_secret=''
access_token=''
access_secret=''

auth = tweepy.auth.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_secret)
api = tweepy.API(auth)

global conn
conn=pymysql.connect(db='twitter', user='root' , host= 'localhost' , port=3307)
global cursor
cursor=conn.cursor()
print("entering loop")

while True:
    query=cursor.execute("select twitter_name from timj_users where found_followers is null and twitter_name is not null order by id asc limit 1")
    if query>0:
        results=cursor.fetchone()
        timj_handle=results[0]
        user = tweepy.Cursor(api.followers, screen_name=timj_handle).items()
        try:
            followers=user.follower_count
            location=user.location
            cursor.execute("update timj_users set followers=%s,location=%s,found_followers=1 where twitter_name=%s" , (followers, location ,handle))
            conn.commit()
            print("user followers received")
            if followers>100:
                user.follow()
                cursor.execute("update users set followed=1 where twitter_name=%s" , (handle))
                conn.commit()
                print("User followed")
        except:
            time.sleep(15*60)
            print 'We got a timeout ... Sleeping for 15 minutes'

    else:
        print("All users processed")
        break
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're not getting an error from python and the console is just "hanging" you did actually connect to the Twitter, but since you have nothing in the code to display any message you get from Twitter you won't receive anything.

You need to include this in the code:

```
def on_error(self, status_code):
    print(status_code)
```

That code will give you provide you with the number that is related to Twitter's [Error Codes & Responses](https://dev.twitter.com/overview/api/response-codes).

To be more clear:

```
    except:
        time.sleep(15*60)
        print 'We got a timeout ... Sleeping for 15 minutes'
```

That exception is not being used what you think it is. The exception is raised if there's an error in the code you're writing, *not* errors you obtain from twitter.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this line

`auth = tweepy.auth.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)`

should be

`auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)`

However, you have written a really complicated for a beginner.  Can I suggest that you run a more basic Tweepy program, and see what you get.

```
import tweepy

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)

api = tweepy.API(auth)

public_tweets = api.home_timeline()
for tweet in public_tweets:
    print tweet.text
```

(From the [Tweepy Documentation](http://tweepy.readthedocs.org/en/v3.4.0/getting_started.html#introduction))

Comment: Hi, I made the change that you suggested but the same issue is recurring. The code that you have given works when run from my laptop

Comment: Do you have a database set up with the same parameters as you're using in your code?